When need to call the Objective C nsautoreleasepool() on Rust side?
I use the objc2 library and their AppKit bindings in my project.
Everything is good but I am not an Objective C developer and a little confused by the Rust implementation of autoreleasepool.
For example,
fn set_icon(&self, icon: Option<&Icon>) {
    autoreleasepool(|_| {
        let mtm = MainThreadMarker::from(self);
        let app = NSApp(mtm);
        match icon {
            Some(icon) => {
                let ns_image = icon.get_impl().get_native();
                unsafe { app.setApplicationIconImage(Some(&ns_image)) };
            }
            None => unsafe { app.setApplicationIconImage(None) },
        }
    });
}

macOS Icon implementation:
struct IconImpl {
    mtm:    MainThreadMarker,
    native: MainThreadBound<Id<NSImage>>,
}

impl IconImpl {
    fn get_native(&self) -> &Id<NSImage> { self.native.get(self.mtm) }
}

Should I use the autoreleasepool in such cases?
Theoretically there can be an existed icon which will be replaced by a new one and it will lead to memory leaks (at least I think so). On the other hand, the previous icon can be set from the Icon instance too and then I don't need to release it cuz my Icon implementation will release it automatically on drop().
